# Last digit of power list

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, exponent

**Outline of problem:**

Please note I will abuse the life out of `^` and use it as a power symbol, despite the caret symbol being the bitwise XOR operator in JS.

Take a list of positive integers,

```
[ x_0, x_1, ..., x_n ]
```

and find the last digit of the equation given by

```
x_0 ^ ( x_1 ^ (... ^ x_n ) ... )
```

I'll call this function `LD(...)` for the rest of this question.

Example: For a list of integers `a = [2, 2, 2, 2]` and given that `2 ^ (2 ^ (2 ^ 2)) = 65536`, it's easy to see that `LD(a) = 6`.

Note that `0 ^ 0 === 1` for this question, consistent with `x ^ 0 === 1`, but not with `0 ^ x === 0`.

---

**What I've achieved so far**

It's easy to conclude that `x ^ 0 === 1`, no matter what.

It's also pretty easy to conclude that last digits of powers "loop" around if you do a few test cases:

```
LD(2 ^ 1) = 2,
LD(2 ^ 2) = 4,
LD(2 ^ 3) = 8,
LD(2 ^ 4) = 6,
LD(2 ^ 5) = 2, // Notice we've looped from hereon
LD(2 ^ 6) = 4,
LD(2 ^ 7) = 8,
...
```

So if we know the count of numbers that are in the loop for a particular base (4 for the above example of the base 2), we can use the modulus of that count to work out the last digit.

E.g., `LD(2 ^ 55) === LD(2 ^ (55 % 4)) === LD(2 ^ 3)`

And so with a bit of maths, we can get ourselves a nice array-of-arrays for each last digit, where the index of the array-of-arrays is the base and the index of each array is the modulus of the loop length:

```
const p = [
  [ 0 ],      // 0^1=0, 0^2=0 ...
  [ 1 ],      // 1^1=1, 1^2=1 ...
  [ 2,4,8,6 ] // 2^1=2, 2^2=4 ...
  [ 3,9,7,1 ] // 3^1=3, 3^2=9 ...
  [ 4,6 ]     
  [ 5 ]       
  [ 6 ]       
  [ 7,9,3,1 ] 
  [ 8,4,2,6 ] 
  [ 9,1 ]     
];
```

Example of usage: `LD(3^7) === p[3][7-1 % 4]` - note that we have to subtract one from the exponent as each array is 0-based.

So we arrive at the JavaScript:

```
LD(Math.pow(a,b)) === p[a % 10][(b-1) % p[a % 10].length]
```

The `a % 10` should be obvious, it takes just the last digit of the base number as the index in our array-of-arrays, as any non-units do not affect the last digit.

For a list like `[1,2,3]` from the beginning of the question, this can be made recursive. We have an initial value of 1, in case of empty lists, as `x^1 === x`, and we reverse the list to make use of accumulation of the `.reduce()` method:

```
[1,2,3].reduceRight( (a,v) => 
  p[v % 10][(a-1) % p[v % 10].length], 1)
```

Following through so that makes sense would look like the following:

- First up, `a = 1 (initial value), v = 3`; then `p[3 % 10] === p[3] === [ 3,9,7,1 ]`, and thus `[ 3,9,7,1 ][ (1-1) % [ 3,9,7,1 ].length] === [ 3,9,7,1 ][ 0 % 4 ] === 3`.
- Then, `a = 3 (last iteration), v = 2`; so `p[2] === [ 2,4,8,6 ]`, and so `[ 2,4,8,6 ][ 2 % 4 ] === 8`.
- Finally, `a = 8, v = 1`; `p[1] === [ 1 ]`, and `[ 1 ][ 8 % 1 ] === 1`.

So, we get `LD([1, 2, 3 ]) === 1`, which isn't hard to verify: `1 ^ (2 ^ 3) === 1 ^ 8 === 1`.

---

**The problem:**

This works, so long as the exponent is not over 10 and there isn't another iteration after that. However, if there is things go awry. Let me explain:

Say we have the array, `a = [ 2,2,2,2 ]`. As `1` is our initial value, the list is initially `a = [ 1,2,2,2,2 ]`. Using the reduction above:

- First iteration `a = 1, v = 2` (remembering that our `.reduce` has `1` as it's initial value):

  - `p[2 % 10][(1-1) % p[2 % 10].length]`
  - `= [ 2,4,8,6 ][0 % 4]`
  - `= 2`
  - *Easily verified by `2 ^ 1 = 2`*, our list is now [ 2,2,2,2 ]
- Second iteration `a = 2, v = 2`:

  - `p[2 % 10][(2-1) % p[2 % 10].length]`
  - `= [ 2,4,8,6 ][1 % 4]`
  - `= 4`
  - *Easily verified by `2 ^ 2 = 4`*, our list is now [ 4,2,2 ]
- Third iteration `a = 4, v = 2`:

  - `p[2 % 10][(4-1) % p[2 % 10].length]`
  - `= [ 2,4,8,6 ][3 % 4]`
  - `= 6`
  - *Easily verified by `2 ^ 4 = 16`*, our list is now [ 16,2 ]
- Fourth iteration, **where the issue becomes apparent**. `a = 6, v = 2`:

  - `p[2 % 10][(6-1) % p[2 % 10].length]`
  - `= [ 2,4,8,6 ][5 % 4]`
  - `= 4`
  - *Easily disproved by `2 ^ 16 = 65536`*.

And if you study that for a while it becomes obvious why. The third step in the final iteration,

```
= [ 2,4,8,6 ][5 % 4] = p[ 2,4,8,6 ][1]
```

should be

```
= [ 2,4,8,6 ][15 % 4] = p[ 2,4,8,6 ][3]
```

Therefore giving an incorrect result.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way, based on the previous exponent, to capture that "offset" created by only passing on the last digit of the previous iteration? Can I somehow pass on the `6` in that last iteration with another piece of information so that the modulus is correct?

So instead of just returning

```
p[v % 10][(a-1) % p[v % 10].length)
```

maybe it could return

```
[ 
  p[v % 10][fn(a[0], a[1]) % p[v % 10].length],
  **some other clever information here to use in the calculation to make the modulus correct**
]
```

where `fn(a[0], a[1])` uses both the accumulated value from before, as well as some other information to calculate the correct mod value. This doesn't necessarily have to be an array, maybe an object or tuple as @aec pointed out in the comments.

One (terrible) solution would be to keep track of the previous iteration in the accumulator (e.g., for that last step, instead of returning `6`, I could return `16` and use that for the next iteration, which would give the correct index). However, it's very impractical if the numbers were very large! Say the previous step had the numbers `4142` and `623`, it's not practical to calculate `4142^623` and pass that on.

Please note that I understand there are other solutions to this, but I am curious if I can change this code to solve this problem in the single `.reduce` statement I've written. So is it possible to solve this problem by modifying:

```
array.reduceRight( (a,v) => 
  p[v % 10][(a-1) % p[v % 10].length], 1)
```

despite the discussed accumulator problem? It nearly works, and I think I'm one trick away from it working!

**Please note the brackets!** The list `[3, 14, 16]` is equivalent to `3 ^ (14 ^ 16) !== (3 ^ 14) ^ 16`

A few tests to check against, which can be verified for function call `LU(array)`, where `array` is the array of numbers:

```js
// Current attempt
const p = [
  [ 0 ],      // 0^1=0, 0^2=0 ...
  [ 1 ],      // 1^1=1, 1^2=1 ...
  [ 2,4,8,6 ], // 2^1=2, 2^2=4 ...
  [ 3,9,7,1 ], // 3^1=3, 3^2=9 ...
  [ 4,6 ],     
  [ 5 ],       
  [ 6 ],       
  [ 7,9,3,1 ], 
  [ 8,4,2,6 ], 
  [ 9,1 ]     
];

// CURRENT ATTEMPT
let LU = array => 
  array.reduceRight( (a,v) => 
    a === 0 ? 1 : p[v % 10][(a-1) % p[v % 10].length]
  , 1);

let LUTest = (array, expected) => 
  console.log(
    (LU(array) === expected ? "Success" : "Failed"), 
    "for", array, "got", LU(array), "expected", expected);
    
LUTest([ 2, 2, 2 ],    6)
LUTest([ 2, 2, 2, 2 ], 6)
LUTest([ 3, 4, 5 ],    1)
LUTest([ 6, 8, 10 ],   6)
LUTest([ 2, 2, 0 ],    2)
LUTest([ 12, 30, 21 ], 6) 
LUTest([ 0, 0 ],       1) // x^0 === 1 
LUTest([ 0 ],          0)
```

Tested here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=56c82ccd658e09e829f16bb99457bcbc

Thank you for reading!

---

**Further ideas:**

Had a mini-breakthrough! So for any integer that is a base of an exponent (i.e., the `x` in `x^y`), `LD(x) === LD(x % 10)`. This is because the digits past the first (right-to-left) do not affect the unit digit of the exponent result (e.g., `LD(23 ^ 7) === LD(3 ^ 7)`)

Also, as in `const p = [ ...`, the array-of-arrays containing the cycles of unit values, all numbers have cycles of a length with a lowest common multiple of 4. i.e., all cycles are either 1, 2 or 4 numbers (e.g., the `p[3] === [ 3,9,7,1 ]` unit array has length four).

So, we can conclude `LD((x % 10) ^ (y % 4)) === LD(x ^ y)`.

Note however if a number is a multiple of 4, it becomes zero. We don't want this most of the time! You don't want `20` to becomes `0` on the exponent side either - we want the range for `x` to be 1 through 10, and for y to be 1 through 4:

So, `LD((x % 10 || 10) ^ (y % 4 || 4)) === LD(x ^ y)`. We can handle the special cases with

```
if (x === 0) { 
  return 0 // 0^anything = 0, including 0^0 for argument's sake.
} else if (y === 0) {
  return 1 // anything ^ 0 = 1, excluding 0^0
} else {
  ...
}
```

This is very interesting! It means it is now reasonable to calculate `LD(x ^ y)`, but I'm not sure what to do with this information.

Comment: This has got to go down as one of the most detailed questions I've seen on SO, Kudos for that.   But the only thing missing -> `single .reduce statement I've written.`  I can't seem to see it here...

Comment: @Keith Please see the edit! Hopefully it's as clear as it is detailed :)

Comment: I mean, the accumulator could simply be an object or a tuple

Comment: @aec Yes it could be! Any solutions involving either an object or tuple you can think of?

Comment: Hint: `reduceRight` :-)

Comment: @Bergi !!!!! :O imagine I only found out about `findIndex` the other day too, after all these years.

Comment: Okay, here is the thing. The last digits of the number "2" loop every 4. We can't use 10, because 10 doesn't divide 4. We have to use 100. My proposition is that you use a `mods = [10,10,100,100,...]` lookup and instead of saying `a % 10` you say `a % mods[a]`

Comment: @aec I'm very curious about your comment. If you could post an answer and walk me through one iteration of it, I'd would be very very grateful. Wish I could reward more than one upvote for such fantastic answers, I've been scratching my head for several hours over this!

Comment: Re your abuse of the caret – you could use `**` which is the exponentiation operator in JavaScript ;)

Comment: @NickBull ok, I'll look into that but see my answer if you can and let me know if I am missing something. I just changed the order of calculation o.o

Comment: Before processing the array, if we go through it and change every value that has a 0 to its immediate right with a 1 then it would work though (I think). I can implement that if you like

Comment: ah no, not like that. I implemented it into my answer. I mean 3^2^0^5 -> 3^1^5

Comment: @aec I guess if you're pre-collapsing the array you might as well discard the rest of it (0^5 = 0, 2^0 = 1, so no need to leave the 5). But this doesn't solve the problem with exponents >= 10 as NickBull pointed out

Comment: @meowgoesthedog HAH! True, true. By that logic I think within the reduce function I can stop calculating soon as I reach a position where mod4 of power calculated is 0. My solution would increasingly start resembling yours :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Finally!** after doing some digging about I realized I can modify the initial idea and get the answer I wanted:

```
let LD = (as) =>
  as.reduceRight((acc, val) =>
    Math.pow(val < 20 ? val : (val % 20 + 20), acc < 4 ? acc : (acc % 4 + 4)) 
  , 1) % 10
```

Tests:

```js
let LD = (as) =>
  as.reduceRight((acc, val) =>
    Math.pow(val < 20 ? val : (val % 20 + 20), acc < 4 ? acc : (acc % 4 + 4)) 
  , 1) % 10

let LDTest = (array, expected) => 
  console.log((LD(array) === expected ? "Success" : "Failed"), 
    "for", array, "got", LD(array), "expected", expected);

LDTest([ 2, 2, 2 ],    6)
LDTest([ 2, 2, 2, 2 ], 6)
LDTest([ 3, 4, 5 ],    1)
LDTest([ 6, 8, 10 ],   6)
LDTest([ 2, 2, 0 ],    2)
LDTest([ 12, 30, 21 ], 6) 
LDTest([ 0, 0 ],       1) // x^0 === 1 
LDTest([ 0 ],          0)
```

So why `modulo 20`? Because a modulus of 10 loses precision in the cases such as `[ 2,2,2,2 ]`, when we hit the last step as from the question example:

> Fourth iteration, where the issue becomes apparent. `a = 6, v = 2`:
>
> `p[2 % 10][(6-1) % p[2 % 10].length]`
>
> `= [ 2,4,8,6 ][5 % 4]`
>
> `= 4`
>
> Easily disproved by `2 ^ 16 = 65536`.

By simply allowing a multiple up to 20, we have the LCM (lowest common multiple) for each count of the array, as well as for the length of `p`, which is 10. (LCM([ 1,2,4,10 ]) === 20).

However, as the exponential is now never higher than `40^8` (approximately 6 trillion), and as it is taken to the modulo of 4 in the next iteration, we can simply do the exponential and return the answer each time.

Of course to get the digit in the final case, we need to take modulo of 10 to just return that last digit.

---

**There's still some stuff I'm not understanding here.**

We allow any value under the modulo value to retain its value with the ternary operators. E.g., for the exponent, `prev < 4 ? prev : (prev % 4 + 4)`. However I initially believed this to be `prev === 0 ? 0 : (prev % 4 + 4)`.

This is because th exponent of zero does not have the same ending digit as the other multiples of the modulo, it always equals 1 (`x ^ 0 === 1`). So, by adding 4, we get a value that does have the same last digit, and by leaving zero alone we still get 1 for zero exponents.

Why is it that `prev < 4 ? prev : (prev % 4 + 4)` was required to make this answer correct? Why is e.g., `prev = 3`, need to be `3` instead of adding 4 like the others?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Sorry I had a previous attempt in the test and another as the answer above. Please retry the tests :p

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I won't lie to you I still don't really understand how comes. I wrote it initially as another equivalent way of writing `acc === 0 ? 0 : ...` as stated at the bottom, but it seems that doing so for all values below the modulo is what made it finally work. Any insight into why would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your top-down approach is somewhat flawed, because `LD(b)` is not the only determining factor in `LD(a^b)`, unlike with `a` - i.e. **all** digits of `b` influence the value of `LD(a^b)`. Therefore, with a top-down algorithm, it only makes sense to compute the `LD` *at the end*, which kind of defeats the point.

---

That's not to say the formula you derived is useless - quite the opposite.

Looking at the inner index, we see that `(b - 1) % p[a % 10].length` could potentially be computed recursively bottom-up. So what are the possible values of `L = p[a % 10].length`? 1, 2, and 4. The corresponding possible values for `I = (b - 1) % L` are:

- For `L = 1`, `I = 0` trivially.
- For `L = 2`, `I = 0` if `b` is odd. Let `b = c ^ d`, and note that `b` is odd if either `c` is odd or `d = 0`, otherwise even. Thus this case is also trivial if we peek at the next number in the array.
- For `L = 4`, `I` is simply the last digit of `b - 1` in *base 4* (call it `LD4`). We can compute an analogous digit table, and process the rest of the array as before:

  ```
  // base 4 table
  const q = [
     [0],  // 0^1=0 ...
     [1],  // 1^1=1 ...
     [2, 0, 0, 0, ..... ], // infinitely recurring
     [3, 1], // 3^1=3, 3^2=1, 3^3=3, 3^4=1 ...
  ];
  ```

Ah. Well, since there are so few cases, a few if-clauses won't hurt:

```
LD2(a) | LD2(a^b)
----------------------------
0      | 1 if b = 0, else 0
1      | 1 always

LD4(a) | LD4(a^b)
----------------------------------------
0      | 1 if b = 0, else 0
1      | 1 always
2      | 1 if b = 0, 2 if b = 1, else 0
3      | 3 if b odd, else 1
```

With the assumption that `0^0 = 1`. Also, `LD4(b - 1) = LD4(b + 3)`.

---

Code:

```
function isEnd(a, i)
{
   return (i > a.length - 1);
}

function isZero(a, i)
{
   if (!isEnd(a, i))
      if (a[i] == 0)
         return !isZero(a, i+1);
   return false;
}

function isUnity(a, i)
{
   if (isEnd(a, i) || a[i] == 1)
      return true;
   return isZero(a, i+1);
}

function isOdd(a, i)
{
   if (isEnd(a, i) || a[i] % 2 == 1)
      return true;
   return isZero(a, i+1);
}

function LD2(a, i)
{
   if (isEnd(a, i) || a[i] % 2 == 1)
      return 1;
   return isZero(a, i+1) ? 1 : 0;
}

function LD4(a, i)
{
   if (isEnd(a, i)) return 1;
   switch (a[i] % 4) {
      case 0: return isZero(a, i+1) ? 1 : 0;
      case 1: return 1;
      case 2: 
         if (isZero(a, i+1)) return 1;
         if (isUnity(a, i+1)) return 2;
         return 0;
      case 3: return isOdd(a, i+1) ? 3 : 1;
      default: return -1; // exception?
   }
}

const p = [
   [ 0 ],      // 0^1=0, 0^2=0 ...
   [ 1 ],      // 1^1=1, 1^2=1 ...
   [ 2,4,8,6 ], // 2^1=2, 2^2=4 ...
   [ 3,9,7,1 ], // 3^1=3, 3^2=9 ...
   [ 4,6 ],     
   [ 5 ],      
   [ 6 ],      
   [ 7,9,3,1 ],
   [ 8,4,2,6 ],
   [ 9,1 ]
];

function LD10(a)
{
   let LDa = a[0] % 10;
   if (isZero(a, 1)) return 1; // corner case not present in tables
   const row = p[LDa];
   switch (row.length) {
      case 1: return row[0];
      case 2: return row[1 - LD2(a, 1)];
      case 4: return row[(LD4(a, 1) + 3) % 4];
      default: return -1; // exception?
   }
}
```

The above code now passes all test cases.

Comment: This looks like the answer! Will check through properly on lunch. Fantastic!

Comment: @NickBull thanks. I'll try to come up with a top-down solution like yours, but from the current reasoning I don't think that will be possible :/

Comment: Fails for `[ 2, 2, 2, 0 ]` - returns `6` instead of `4`

Comment: @NickBull Ah I see - guess the only 3 numbers thing wasn't right after all. But it should be easy to fix - I'll do it when I have time.

Comment: check out the update at the bottom and see if that's helpful at all.

Comment: @NickBull ok updated with fixed code - now works for **all** cases including the likes of [2, 2, 2, 0] and array sizes less than 3. Also handles 0^0=1 correctly as you defined. Apologies for my C-esque way of coding, I'm clearly not a functional programming guy haha

Comment: Please don't hate me. But... I think it fails for `275232^(84547^729410)`. http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=56c82ccd658e09e829f16bb99457bcbc

Comment: This is a super impressive answer so far btw. Awesome to read through and learn from :)

Comment: @NickBull wow that's interesting, I have no idea why it fails for these numbers (they're big but nowhere near the limit for integers). I'll have a look, thanks for letting me know

Comment: They're randomly generated and tested. Frustrating question eh! :(

Comment: @NickBull a-hah I found the source of the error - an incorrect NOT operator in `isOdd`. Removing it fixed the problem (get 2 as expected), and also did not affect the previous test cases (which is probably why I didn't catch it).

Comment: Great answer @meow! I've solved it in the way I wanted to however, managing to keep it to just a modification of the one-liner. Your answer is a very challenging way of doing it too! Wouldn't have thought to do this :)

Comment: Also per your first comment, you were basically right - you do have to calculate the exponent for a top-down algorithm. But thanks to some clever technicalities, you can reduce the base and exponent before performing the exponential and still get the same unit at the end. Thank you again!